# Have any lawsuits been successful against a sitting US president?

Tags: united-states, president, law

I read an article in my newspaper today about the vast number of lawsuits filed against current US President Trump. I can't recall any lawsuits against previous presidents, but I admit that I may not be well-informed.

Have any lawsuits been successful against a sitting US president? To be clear, I'm looking for a lawsuit against the president himself, rather than a particular bill or government agency.

Comment: There was the Obamacare lawsuit.   Not sure if a lawsuit against a president's bill is what you're talking about or specific suits against the man.

Comment: @userLTK I'm interested in specific suits against the man, rather than their bill. I've edited the question to clarify.

Comment: @Thunderforge The case in my answer was against Bill Clinton himself, not any agency

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Yup, you've definitely found a case that I'm interested in. I'll leave the question open for a while though to see if any other answers emerge before deciding to accept.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the most important case here is [*Clinton v. Jones*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinton_v._Jones). First, it's a case that Bill Clinton lost while he was a sitting president; so that directly answers your question.

More importantly, it held that a sitting president is no different than a private citizen for actions done before or during a presidency that are not official actions of the office. In other words, the Supreme Court held that the president can be sued even while he is in office.

Comment: Clinton v. Jones wasn't the lawsuit that Bill Clinton lost. It was the Supreme Court case that allowed the lawsuit against Clinton, Jones v. Clinton, to proceed. Clinton settled that lawsuit before it went to trial. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paula_Jones#Jones_v._Clinton

Comment: @RossRidge there are two Clinton v Jones cases. Clinton lost one and settled the other

Comment: No, there was only one **Clinton v Jones** case. It was the Supreme Court case you linked. That case was an appeal of **Jones v Clinton**, a case before the US Court of Appeals, Eight Circuit, which in turn was an appeal of certain pre-trial decisions made in **Jones v Clinton** a lawsuit before United States Court for the Eastern District of Arkansas. Bill Clinton lost all three cases, the courts in the two appeal cases deciding against him and he settled the lawsuit for the full claimed amount before the trial actually stated.

Comment: A should add there was also second Jones v Clinton case before the 8th Circuit, an appeal of the District Court's summary judgment and dismissal of the Jones v Clinton lawsuit before it. This appeal was withdrawn when Bill Clinton settled.